# Debugging .NET dll from script component (SSIS)

Tags: c#, ssis, scripting, debugging, components

Is there a way to debug .Net dll from SSIS Script Component which is being  referenced.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach Visual Studio to any local process (or a remote process if the [remote debugger is set up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).)

1. Open the DLL project in Visual Studio
2. From the Debug menu (or Tools menu) select Attach to Process.
3. Click the "Select..." button next to the box labeled "Attach To". Make sure that Debug These Code Types / Managed Code is checked.
4. In the Available Processes list, find the SSIS process. I can't remember the process name off hand, but it should have x86, Managed in the type column. Might have to check "Show Processes from All Users".
5. Click attach.

Now you can break into the debugger as you normally would and breakpoints should get hit. If the debug symbols can't be loaded for whatever reason, open the Modules window, find the managed DLL, right click and "Load Symbols" to find them.

Comment: Can you please expand on how to load the symbols? I am attempting to debug a custom assembly deployed to the GAC and none of the assembly's breakpoints are active because they all say "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." When I try to load the assembly's symbols in the Script Component debugger, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

[System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx)() and  [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx)() can be useful with this type of problem.  However try "attach to proccess" in the debug menu as Josh say first, as it it easyer when it works.